# Can I search on a specific line with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to use `re.search()` to search for a pattern on a line I choose, or starting on a line I specify. Is this possible?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Do you have any example and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: isolate that line using normal string manipulation and pass only that line to `re.search()`.

For example:

```
lines = data.split('\n')
a = re.search('regex', lines[3])
```